# C# custom INT struct or class that stores min/max/prev values

Tags: c#, struct

I'm trying to write a custom class or struct (still not sure which one should I use) that keeps itself its min/max and previous value.

So far I have everything worked, but considering this is a normal INT value, I would like to do the regular things with operators, such as:

```
var m = new stMetric();
m = 5;
m += 5;
```

The idea is that the defaults operators behave like a normal INT value would do.

Here is my Struct definition currently, But cant get the override operators to work properly.

```
internal struct stMetric {
  private int _value;
  private int? _valueMin;
  private int? _valueMax;
  private int? _valuePrev;

  public stMetric() { }
  public stMetric(int value) { Value = value; }

  public int Value { get => _value; set => SetValue(value); }
  public readonly int Min => _valueMin ?? 0;
  public readonly int Max => _valueMax ?? 0;
  public readonly int Previous => _valuePrev ?? 0;

  public override string ToString() => Value.ToString();

  private void SetValue(int value) {
    _valuePrev = _value;
    _value = value;
    if (_value < _valueMin || _valueMin == null) { _valueMin = value; }
    if (_value > _valueMax || _valueMax == null) { _valueMax = value; }
  }

  public static implicit operator int(stMetric v) => v.Value;
  public static explicit operator stMetric(int v) => new(v);

}
```

Comment: If you want to do `= 5`, that's an implicit cast, so your last operator shouldn't be explicit.

Comment: Why have you defined a separate `SetValue` method?

Comment: @Enigmativity idk, I thought I needed it to calculate the min/max/prev , but open to suggestions

Comment: Don't forget the basic difference between a _Value Type_ and a _Reference Type_, you get a new instance of a `struct` after every assignment. As a result, they really need to be immutable. If you do this as a `struct` expected behavior you don't really expect. Do it as a class that has value semantics

Comment: @Flydog57 good hint, as I mentioned there is no preference, but according to your comment I should go with a class instead, that's a good starting point

Comment: @TotalZero - Just wrap up the `SetValue` method into the setter for the property. That's what they are there for.

Comment: Does the `st` in front of `stMetric` stand for `struct`? If so, you should drop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to make the code work exactly the way that you want.

Here's the closest I could get for you:

```
public sealed class Metric : IEquatable<Metric>
{
    public int Value { get; init; }
    public int? Previous { get; init; }
    public int Max { get; init; }
    public int Min { get; init; }

    // new Metric(value: )
    public Metric(int value) =>
        (this.Value, this.Previous, this.Max, this.Min)
            = (value, null, value, value);

    // new Metric(value: , previous: , max: , min: )
    private Metric(int value, int? previous, int max, int min) =>
        (this.Value, this.Previous, this.Max, this.Min)
            = (value, previous, max, min);

    public Metric Update(int value) =>
        new Metric(value, this.Value, Math.Max(value, this.Value), Math.Min(value, this.Value));
    
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Metric ? this.Equals((Metric)obj) : false;

    public bool Equals(Metric obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(this.Value, obj.Value)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<int?>.Default.Equals(this.Previous, obj.Previous)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(this.Max, obj.Max)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(this.Min, obj.Min)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode(this.Value);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<int?>.Default.GetHashCode(this.Previous);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode(this.Max);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode(this.Min);
        return hash;
    }

    public static explicit operator int(Metric metric) => metric.Value;
    public static implicit operator Metric(int value) => new(value);
    
    public override string ToString() =>
        $"{{ Value = {this.Value}, Previous = {this.Previous}, Max = {this.Max}, Min = {this.Min} }}";

public static Metric operator +(Metric left, Metric right) =>
    new Metric(
        left.Value + right.Value,
        null,
        Math.Max(left.Value + right.Value, Math.Max(left.Max, right.Max)),
        Math.Min(left.Value + right.Value, Math.Min(left.Min, right.Min)));

public static Metric operator -(Metric left, Metric right) =>
    new Metric(
        left.Value - right.Value,
        null,
        Math.Max(left.Value - right.Value, Math.Max(left.Max, right.Max)),
        Math.Min(left.Value - right.Value, Math.Min(left.Min, right.Min)));

    public static bool operator ==(Metric left, Metric right) =>
        object.ReferenceEquals(left, null)
            ? object.ReferenceEquals(right, null)
            : left.Equals(right);

    public static bool operator !=(Metric left, Metric right) => !(left == right);
}
```

The code you posted translates to this:

```
var m = new Metric(42);
m = 5;
m += 5;
```

I had to put a number in the constructor (which you didn't have)

This results in:

[image: m]

There's no way to deal with assignment overloads so going from 42 to 5 like this doesn't remember the previous value. You need to abandon all hope of using operator overloads if you're wanting to keep track of previous values.

To make the `Previous` property work I added an `Update` function.

```
Metric m1 = 42;
Metric m2 = m1.Update(49);
Metric m3 = m1.Update(33);
```

[image: Metric Samples]

I did flip around your conversion operators to work like this:

```
int i1 = (int)m1;
int i2 = (int)m2;
int i3 = (int)m3;
```

Going from `int` to `Metric` is a widening operation so it can be `implicit`, but going from `Metric` to `int` is narrowing so it must be `explicit`.

---

There is a significant challenge in understanding what the `Previous` value should be in something like this:

```
Metric m1 = 3;
Metric m2 = 5;
Metric m3 = 2;

Metric m4 = m1 + m2 - m3;
```

[image: Previous Sample]

---

You might want to consider a different structure to store your values.

Try this:

```
public sealed class Metric : IEquatable<Metric>
{
    public int Value { get; init; }
    private string Operator { get; init; }
    private Metric[] Sources { get; init; }

    public int Max => this.Sources.Select(x => x.Max).StartWith(this.Value).Max();
    public int Min => this.Sources.Select(x => x.Min).StartWith(this.Value).Min();
    
    // new Metric(value: )
    public Metric(int value) => (this.Value, this.Operator, this.Sources) = (value, "=",  new Metric[] { });

    // new Metric(value: , previous: , max: , min: )
    private Metric(int value, string @operator, Metric[] sources) =>
        (this.Value, this.Operator, this.Sources)
            = (value, @operator, sources);

    public Metric Update(int value) => new Metric(value, "!", new[] { this });

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Metric ? this.Equals((Metric)obj) : false;

    public bool Equals(Metric obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(this.Value, obj.Value)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode(this.Value);
        return hash;
    }

    public static explicit operator int(Metric metric) => metric.Value;
    public static implicit operator Metric(int value) => new(value);

    public override string ToString() =>
        this.Operator == "=" && this.Sources.IsEmpty()
        ? $"{this.Value}"
        : $"{this.Value} is {this.Operator}({String.Join(", ", this.Sources.Select(s => $"{s}"))})";

    public static Metric operator +(Metric left, Metric right) =>
        new Metric(
            left.Value + right.Value,
            "+",
            new[] { left, right });

    public static Metric operator -(Metric left, Metric right) =>
        new Metric(
            left.Value - right.Value,
            "-",
            new[] { left, right });

    public static bool operator ==(Metric left, Metric right) =>
        object.ReferenceEquals(left, null)
            ? object.ReferenceEquals(right, null)
            : left.Equals(right);

    public static bool operator !=(Metric left, Metric right) => !(left == right);
}
```

This keeps track of the underlying source values and Let's you compute `Min` and `Max` at any time and you can see your previous values with a simple `.ToString()`.

```
Metric m1 = 3;
m1 = m1.Update(4);
Metric m2 = 5;
Metric m3 = 2;

Metric m4 = m1 + m2 - m3;
```

A `.ToString()` on `m4` gives you `7 is -(9 is +(4 is !(3), 5), 2)`.

The mins & maxes are:

[image: Mins & Maxes]

Comment: First and foremost, thanks a million for your super detailed answer, you certainly covered and answered a lot of questions I had in mind, truly appreciate taking the time to do this.

Comment: Secondly, you answered my biggest fear, and the main reason I wanted to do this, 
There's no way to deal with assignment overloads so going from 42 to 5 like this doesn't remember the previous value.
That's a shame, ALL I basically wanted was avoid having to call a method to set a new value

Comment: btw, how did you get that nifty window showing the values of Metric ?

Comment: @TotalZero - I use https://www.linqpad.net for most of my coding now.